# Will a view complete even if a user times out?

Tags: python, django, web

If I have a view in Django such as

```
def hello(request):
    first_up(request)

    do_stuff(request)
    return render(request, 'hello.html')
```

If a user requests this page, but times out before the view can complete or navigates away before the view reaches the 'render' will the view still complete it's task?

For example if the view finishes the `first_up` function but the user navigates away or closes their browser etc. Will the `do_stuff` function still complete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hello(request) function is called the function will complete / return regardless of if the user has dropped the connection or not.

Unless of course an exception occurs, but that would depend on the code in do_stuff() and first_up().

Comment: np, one thing worth mentioning is if you have long-running tasks that you want to complete you should probably look at django-celery or something similar to offload those tasks and do them asynchronously.  It will free up web-server threads and separate web logic from task runners.